# add django_contrab schedules returns "Unknown command: 'crontab'"

Tags: python, django, unix, cron, django-crontab

I have configured django-crontab accordingly in my newly installed WSL2, ubuntu. And, when I did run `python manage.py crontab add` it worked just fine yesterday. Today, I tried to run the command again, and it returns:

```sh
Unknown command: 'crontab'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage
```

```
CRONJOBS = [
    ('*/5 * * * *', 'coreapp.cron.update_survey_summary')
]

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django_crontab",
    "drf_spectacular",
    "rest_framework",
    ....
# coreapp.cron.update_survey_summary
from coreapp.models import Event, User

def update_survey_summary():
    u = User.objects.get(id=6)
    e = Event(
      creator=u, 
      title="Event ", 
      location="Algeria",
      hosted_by="Admin"
    )
    print("saving...")
    e.save()
```

One other thing is that the django app would run successfully with `python3 manage.py runserver`. Which I find weird.

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to activate the correct environment?

E.g.

```
    conda activate NameOfEnv
```

Best of